# STL __merge_without_buffer algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, d

Where can I get a decent high-level description of the algorithm used in `__merge_without_buffer()` in the C++ STL?  I'm trying to reimplement this code in the D programming language, with some enhancements.  I can't seem to grok what it's doing at the algorithmic level from just reading the STL source code because there are too many low-level details obscuring it.  Also, I don't want to just blindly translate the code because then, if it didn't work I wouldn't know why, and I wouldn't be able to add my enhancements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`__merge_without_buffer()` is performing an **in-place merge**, as the merge step of an in-place merge sort.  It takes as input two ranges of data `[first, middle)` and `[middle, last)` which are assumed to already be sorted.  The `len1` and `len2` parameters are equal to the lengths of the two input ranges, namely `(middle - first)` and `(last - middle)` respectively.

First, it picks a *pivot* element.  Then, it rearranges the data into the order `A1 B1 A2 B2`, where `A1` is the set of elements in `[first, middle)` that are less than the pivot, `A2` is the set of elements in `[first, middle)` greater than or equal to the pivot, `B1` is the set of elements in `[middle, last)` less than the pivot, and `B2` is the set of elements in `[middle, last)` greater than or equal to the pivot.  Note that the data is originally in the order `A1 A2 B1 B2`, so all we need to do is to turn `A2 B1` into `B1 A2`.  This is with a call to `std::rotate()`, which does just that.

Now we've separated out the elements which are less than the pivot (`A1` and `B1`) from those that are greater than or equal to the pivot (`A2` and `B2`), so now we can recursively merge the two subranges `A1 A2` and `B1 B2`.

How do we choose a pivot?  In the implementation I'm looking at, it chooses the median element from the larger subrange (i.e. if `[first, middle)` has more elements than `[middle, last)`, it chooses the median of `[first, middle)`; otherwise, it chooses the median of `[middle, last)`).  Since the subranges are already sorted, choosing the median is trivial.  This pivot choice ensures that when recursively merging the two subranges, each subproblem is no more than 3/4 the size of the current problem, because in the worst case, at least 1/4 of the elements are larger than or smaller than the pivot.

What is the running time of this?  The `std::rotate()` call takes O(N) time, and we make two recursive calls to ourselves.  This equates to a running time of O(N log N).  However, note that this is only one step in mergesort: remember that in mergesort you first recursively sort both halves and then merge.  Thus, the recurrence relation for the running time of mergesort is now:

`T(N) = 2T(N/2) + O(N log N)`

Plug this into the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), and you get that mergesort now runs in O(N log<sup>2</sup> N) time!

As an interesting final point, consider the following three qualities of a comparison-based sorting algorithm:

1. In-place
2. Stable
3. Runs in O(N log N) time

You can usually only get 2 of these at once - quicksort gets you (1) and (3), mergesort gets you (2) and (3), and an in-place mergesort gets you (1) and (2).  Non-comparison-based sorts such as count sort can achieve all 3, but those sorts can only sort certain data types.  It's possible there exists a comparison-based sort which achieves all 3, but if there is, I'm not aware of its existence, and it's almost certainly much more complicated.

Comment: Does O(N log2 N) mean N (log N)^2?  I was confused, because I thought log2 meant log_2, but the base is irrelevant here.  Also, is the last part "you can only get 2 of these at once" strictly true, or is it simply that the algorithms that get all three are complicated?  My guess is the latter?

Comment: I've edited to address your questions.  I messed up the HTML superscript tag.  log^2 N means (log N)^2.  Although base 2 is implied, the actual base is irrelevant, since it's a constant factor that gets eaten up by the big-O notation.

Comment: In paragraph 3, I think you mean that subranges A1 and B1 get merged together recursively, and subranges A2 and B2 get merged recursively, right? After rotation, there is no subrange A1 A2 anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but now that I know it's O(N log N) not O(N) I'm not even sure I want to bother implementing it anymore, though I think it's a really cool algorithm, so I might just to see how slow it is in practice.

Comment: Note that it's only called when you're low on memory. When callers can allocate a temporary buffer, they don't call the in-place version. They call the O(n) "adaptive" version instead. When it's between "slow" and failure, choose the former.

Comment: The standard quicksort is not in-place, it requires non-constant additional stack. There is a modified quicksort that runs in constant additional memory (storing its stack in the array using clever tricks), but it is rather ineffective, although still O(n*log(n)).

Comment: True, but for most real world uses, O(log N) stack can be considered "almost" in place.  It generates no heap activity and has minimal risk of overflowing the stack.

Comment: I did end up implementing this to satisfy my curiosity, and it's not as slow as I thought.  Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, I messaged Adam Rosenfield off-site, and thought some of you would like to know.  From the standpoint of theory, there do exist algorithms that have "all good three qualities".  See http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=892042 and http://www.springerlink.com/content/bx6d9xv8p6w3d3p4/

Comment: Yes, I've looked at these a little.  They seem incredibly hard to understand and implement, though I'd like to get one working.  I'd assume there's a reason why they're not in STL.