# C++ Merge Sort memory problems

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to write my implementation of merge sort algorithm.
But I can't understand how to use memory correctly. Here is my code:

```
void merge(vector<int>::iterator begin1, vector<int>::iterator end1,
           vector<int>::iterator begin2, vector<int>::iterator end2,
           vector<int>::iterator out) {
    while (begin1 != end1) {
        if (*begin1 <= * begin2 || begin2 == end2) {
            *out++ = *begin1++;
        } else {
            *out++ = *begin2++;
        }
    }
    while (begin1 < end1) {
        *out++ = *begin1++;
    }
    while (begin2 < end2) {
        *out++ = *begin2++;
    } 
}


void merge_sort(vector<int> &v) {
    unsigned long n = v.size();
    if (n == 1) {
        return;
    }
    vector<int> v1;
    v1.assign(v.begin(), v.begin() + n/2);
    vector<int> v2;
    v2.assign(v.begin() + n/2, v.end());
    merge_sort(v1);
    merge_sort(v2);
    merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), v.begin());
    v1.clear();
    v2.clear();
}
```

It works, but it doesn't use the memory effective. How can I improve it?

Comment: Use an iterator range for `merge_sort` too?

Comment: Incidentally, you should change `if (*begin1 <= * begin2 || begin2 == end2)` to `if (begin2 == end2 || *begin1 <= * begin2)`.  Indirecting through `begin2` is illegal if it is equal to `end2`.

Answer (score 1):

The STL can do merge_sort with low memory footprint using std::inplace_merge, see e.g. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge

Here is a high-level description of how an in-place merge is done:
[STL __merge_without_buffer algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438012/stl-merge-without-buffer-algorithm)

Comment: Well yes - but the chances the OP is trying to use this in production code are indistinguishable from zero.  He will be doing this as an educational exercise - in which case he needs to write the code himself.

Comment: @MartinBonner. True. I just found the problem interesting enough to start looking in the std:: headers, now I am looking at the code for std::__merge_without_buffer.